# Mail found by iPad global search operation, but not in Mail app

Tags: ipad, mail.app, ios

Today I discovered this:

If I search my iOS 8 iPad for a certain name, I find three different Emails. All of these are drafts. If I touch one of these findings, mail.app opens the drafts and show them completely.

If I search within mail.app, the application doesn't find the emails. Even if I search 'all folder' and 'search on server' too.

Given these findings:

- Why does the **global iOS 8 search finds** these drafts but mail.app not?
- How my I **delete those drafts**, although mail.app doesn't show them using its search operation.

Comment: "How my I delete those drafts" - can you not navigate directly to your Drafts folder?

Comment: ...but otherwise I see the same behaviour as you, "global search (spotlight)" finds "Draft" emails, whereas the Mail app does not. Unless you are actually in the "Drafts" folder when you search! In Mail, searching "All Inboxes" seems to be the best I can get?! (Which is not the same as "all mail".)

Comment: @w3d No. Those documents do not appear in the drafts folder.

Comment: @w3d Even if I search inside the drafts folder, the documents in question do not appear.

Comment: Is it possible that this Draft folder is on a different account? When you find these emails via Spotlight and navigate to it via this method and if you then drill up to the account level, is it the account you expect? If you then drill back down to the Drafts folder is the email you just viewed still there?

Comment: @w3d No, the iPad has just one account configured.